# Transaction is ended due to timeout due to updating same table using two Message Drive Beans

Tags: java, ejb

I am using two Message Drive Beans (MDB), to update same table. I am using EJB 3.0 and using transaction type as

`@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW)`

some times one of the methods are getting error like "Transaction is ended due to timeout" and MDB is getting deactivated. Hence , I have to restart the server.

Can I use any other type of transaction attribute `@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.NOT_SUPPORTED)` to avoid the  timeout error ?

Here is my stacktrace.

`[:] CWWMQ0007W: The message endpoint Rsme#RsmeEJB.jar#GemsInqMDB has been paused by the system.  Message delivery failed to the endpoint more than 0 times.  The last attempted delivery failed with the following error: javax.ejb.EJBTransactionRolledbackException: Transaction rolled back; nested exception is: javax.transaction.TransactionRolledbackException: Transaction is ended due to timeout
javax.transaction.TransactionRolledbackException: Transaction is ended due to timeout
    at com.ibm.tx.jta.impl.EmbeddableTranManagerImpl.completeTxTimeout(EmbeddableTranManagerImpl.java:62)
    at com.ibm.tx.jta.impl.EmbeddableTranManagerSet.completeTxTimeout(EmbeddableTranManagerSet.java:85)
    at com.ibm.ejs.csi.TransactionControlImpl.completeTxTimeout(TransactionControlImpl.java:1347)
    at com.ibm.ejs.csi.TranStrategy.postInvoke(TranStrategy.java:242)
    at com.ibm.ejs.csi.TransactionControlImpl.postInvoke(TransactionControlImpl.java:579)
    at com.ibm.ejs.container.EJSContainer.postInvoke(EJSContainer.java:4843)
    at com.maybank.meaa.local.EJSLocal0SLMeaaEntityBean_877f3cd5.insertPD003Result(EJSLocal0SLMeaaEntityBean_877f3cd5.java)
    at com.maybank.meaa.mdbs.GemsInqMDB.onMessage(GemsInqMDB.java:75)
    at com.ibm.ejs.container.MessageEndpointHandler.invokeMdbMethod(MessageEndpointHandler.java:1163)
    at com.ibm.ejs.container.MessageEndpointHandler.invoke(MessageEndpointHandler.java:842)
    at $Proxy27.onMessage(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.mq.connector.inbound.MessageEndpointWrapper.onMessage(MessageEndpointWrapper.java:131)
    at com.ibm.mq.jms.MQSession$FacadeMessageListener.onMessage(MQSession.java:147)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.jms.internal.JmsSessionImpl.run(JmsSessionImpl.java:2665)
    at com.ibm.mq.jms.MQSession.run(MQSession.java:862)
    at com.ibm.mq.connector.inbound.WorkImpl.run(WorkImpl.java:279)
    at com.ibm.ejs.j2c.work.WorkProxy.run(WorkProxy.java:608)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1650)
javax.ejb.EJBTransactionRolledbackException: Transaction rolled back; nested exception is: javax.transaction.TransactionRolledbackException: Transaction is ended due to timeout
Caused by: javax.transaction.TransactionRolledbackException: Transaction is ended due to timeout
    at com.ibm.tx.jta.impl.EmbeddableTranManagerImpl.completeTxTimeout(EmbeddableTranManagerImpl.java:62)
    at com.ibm.tx.jta.impl.EmbeddableTranManagerSet.completeTxTimeout(EmbeddableTranManagerSet.java:85)
    at com.ibm.ejs.csi.TransactionControlImpl.completeTxTimeout(TransactionControlImpl.java:1347)
    at com.ibm.ejs.csi.TranStrategy.postInvoke(TranStrategy.java:242)
    at com.ibm.ejs.csi.TransactionControlImpl.postInvoke(TransactionControlImpl.java:579)
    at com.ibm.ejs.container.EJSContainer.postInvoke(EJSContainer.java:4843)
    at com.maybank.meaa.local.EJSLocal0SLMeaaEntityBean_877f3cd5.insertPD003Result(EJSLocal0SLMeaaEntityBean_877f3cd5.java)
    at com.maybank.meaa.mdbs.GemsInqMDB.onMessage(GemsInqMDB.java:75)
    at com.ibm.ejs.container.MessageEndpointHandler.invokeMdbMethod(MessageEndpointHandler.java:1163)
    at com.ibm.ejs.container.MessageEndpointHandler.invoke(MessageEndpointHandler.java:842)
    at $Proxy27.onMessage(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.mq.connector.inbound.MessageEndpointWrapper.onMessage(MessageEndpointWrapper.java:131)
    at com.ibm.mq.jms.MQSession$FacadeMessageListener.onMessage(MQSession.java:147)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.jms.internal.JmsSessionImpl.run(JmsSessionImpl.java:2665)
    at com.ibm.mq.jms.MQSession.run(MQSession.java:862)
    at com.ibm.mq.connector.inbound.WorkImpl.run(WorkImpl.java:279)
    at com.ibm.ejs.j2c.work.WorkProxy.run(WorkProxy.java:608)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1650)
.`

Comment: Why two MDBs?  Shouldn't it be the responsibility of a single object?  Maybe they're deadlocking each other.  What else writes to that database?  Maybe they're deadlocked with someone else.

Comment: Yes, some times bulk of messages will come . we are receiving the response from two different interfaces and two different queues.

Comment: Are you using an XA driver for your JDBC connection?  You should.  That will make taking the message off the queue and writing to the database a single unit of work.

Comment: None of that is germane.  Are you using an XA driver for your JDBC connection?  It's a different class name: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19159-01/819-3671/gbsor/index.html

Comment: i am using oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver, using Oracle as databse

Comment: I wonder if you need oracle.jdbc.xa.client.OracleXADataSource instead.

Answer (score 1):

**Create two different tables with the same structure to avoid the deadlock instead of using same table for two MDB**

Comment: Yes, we can use two different tables. but the problem is , I have to change logic to display the data at front end and need to migrate the old data into new table. I think, this is not a correct solution.

Answer (score 0):

This error can be caused by normally 2 things
1- EJB Timeout
2- Datasource Timeout

You can configurate both to a greater value.

1 - WebSphere Application servers > <> container properties > Transaction service
Total transaction lifetime timeout - this will be the default value for EJB without this property
Maximum transaction timeout - this wil be the max value for any transaction managed by WAS

2 - Data sources > <> > Connection pools
Connection timeout 
Unused timeout

Normally, the option 1 fix the problem.